# Could someone help me understand what alias_method does in this code

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of alias_method in this code

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter.class_eval do
  alias_method :configure_connection_without_interval, :configure_connection
  define_method :configure_connection do
    configure_connection_without_interval
    execute('SET intervalstyle = iso_8601', 'SCHEMA')
  end
end
```

What is the purpose of line 4 where they call `configure_connection_without_interval` -- doesn't that just call itself?

The code below works for me but I don't fully know what I'm doing and I'm worried it'll create bugs later

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter.class_eval do
  define_method :configure_connection do
    execute('SET intervalstyle = iso_8601', 'SCHEMA')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`alias_method` operates immediately on that line before the method is redefined, preserving the old method under that given name.

That's a common Ruby technique to capture a version of a particular method and wrap it in another. When you're patching a class directly instead of subclassing you'll often be forced to do this.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm finally getting it. So in this case it's preserving the old configure_connection method and just adding `execute('SET intervalstyle = iso_8601', 'SCHEMA')` to that method?

Comment: Exactly as you suspect. You get to control when that operates vs. the existing code during the redefinition, so you can do things before and/or after it.

Comment: "That's a common Ruby technique" – Correction: That **WAS** a common Ruby technique. Now, we have `Module#prepend` which makes the whole thing much cleaner. E.g. Rails, which has popularized this idiom, has removed it again, many many years ago.